# Angular - Custom DaterangePicker in Highchart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I create a highcharts similar to [this](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) in angular (v8). I want to remove default filter an create one custom with help of [ngx daterangepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material). I need to filter the array but is a [complex array](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/msft-c.json). I try to create multiple iterations with foreach but doens´t work.

This is my TS code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { fadeAnimation } from "../../../../animations.component";
import { StockChart } from "angular-highcharts";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as moment from "moment";
declare let AdminLTE: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-metergraph",
  templateUrl: "./graph.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./graph.component.scss"],
  animations: [fadeAnimation]
})
export class MetersGraphComponent implements OnInit {
  chart: StockChart;
  seriesOptions: any = [];
  ranges: any;
  pickerlang: any;
  seriesCounter = 0;
  names = ["MSFT", "AAPL"];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    AdminLTE.init();
    moment.locale("es");
    this.names.forEach((element, i) => {
      this.http
        .get(
          "https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/" +
            element.toLowerCase() +
            "-c.json"
        )
        .forEach((data: any) => {
          this.seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: element,
            data: data
          };
          this.seriesCounter += 1;
          if (this.seriesCounter === this.names.length) {
            this.createGraph();
          }
        });
    });

    this.ranges = {
      Today: [moment(), moment()],
      Yesterday: [moment().subtract(1, "days"), moment().subtract(1, "days")],
      "Last 7 Days": [moment().subtract(6, "days"), moment()],
      "Last 30 Days": [moment().subtract(29, "days"), moment()],
      "This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")],
      "Last Month": [
        moment()
          .subtract(1, "month")
          .startOf("month"),
        moment()
          .subtract(1, "month")
          .endOf("month")
      ]
    };

    this.pickerlang = {
      format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
      direction: "ltr",
      weekLabel: "W",
      cancelLabel: "Cancelar",
      applyLabel: "Aceptar",
      clearLabel: "",
      daysOfWeek: moment.weekdaysMin(),
      monthNames: moment.monthsShort(),
      firstDay: 1
    };

    Highcharts.setOptions({
      lang: {
        loading: "Cargando...",
        months: [
          "Enero",
          "Febrero",
          "Marzo",
          "Abril",
          "Mayo",
          "Junio",
          "Julio",
          "Agosto",
          "Septiembre",
          "Octubre",
          "Noviembre",
          "Diciembre"
        ],
        weekdays: [
          "Domingo",
          "Lunes",
          "Martes",
          "Miércoles",
          "Jueves",
          "Viernes",
          "Sábado"
        ],
        shortMonths: [
          "Ene",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Abr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Ago",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dic"
        ],
        rangeSelectorFrom: "Desde",
        rangeSelectorTo: "Hasta",
        rangeSelectorZoom: "Período",
        downloadPNG: "Descargar imagen PNG",
        downloadJPEG: "Descargar imagen JPEG",
        downloadPDF: "Descargar imagen PDF",
        downloadSVG: "Descargar imagen SVG",
        downloadCSV: "Descargar imagen CSV",
        downloadXLS: "Descargar imagen XLS",
        printChart: "Imprimir",
        resetZoom: "Reiniciar zoom",
        resetZoomTitle: "Reiniciar zoom",
        viewData: "Ver tabla",
        openInCloud: "Ver en web",
        thousandsSep: ",",
        decimalPoint: "."
      }
    });
  }

  createGraph() {
    this.chart = new StockChart({
      xAxis: {
        crosshair: {
          width: 1,
          color: "red"
        }
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
      },
      chart: {
        zoomType: "x",
        panning: true,
        panKey: "shift"
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          showInNavigator: true
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat:
          '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} litros</b><br/>',
        valueDecimals: 2,
        split: true
      },
      series: this.seriesOptions
    });
  }

  change(data: any) {
    console.log(data["startDate"].toJSON().substring(0, 10));
    console.log(data["endDate"].toJSON().substring(0, 10));
    this.seriesOptions.forEach((element: any) => {
      // console.log(element);
      element["data"].forEach(index => {
        //console.log(index[0]);
        index.forEach((datetime: any) => {
          console.log(datetime); //MULTIPLE ITERATIONS FAIL, MAYBE HIGHCHART HAVE A FUNCTION TO FILTER ARRAY WITH  FIELD VALUES.
        });
      });
      // console.log(element["data"]);
      //console.log(element["data"][0]);
    });
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content-header">
    <section class="content">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h5>
            <b>Test</b>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd [locale]="pickerlang" [(ngModel)]="selected" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Rango de fecha" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" [ranges]="ranges"
            [showCustomRangeLabel]="true" [alwaysShowCalendars]="true" />
          <div [chart]="chart"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Finally i add a [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Y3w.png) of page.

So the question is: How can i filter this type of array with values of the timepicker ? Iteration fail. Maybe highchart has a function to send fields values and filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xAxis.setExtremes()` method which allows setting the minimum and maximum of the axes after render time. Try to use it with dates fetched from the date picker (dates has to be provided in milliseconds):

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1536154200000, 1558099800000);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uk0wmjpo/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

**EDIT**

A chart instance could be obtained using the chart's events - context of all chart's events functions is the chart instance.

**Angular demo (using `highcharts-angular` official wrapper):**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-m6pzg

**API reference:**

- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#chart-instance

Comment: I don´t have 'chart' element, not sure how can i call it in angular.